# Typedef, template and const keyword

Tags: c++, templates, constants, typedef

I have a problem using the template with const keyword (for function argument type), to illustrate it i created a tiny code :

```
template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename ... Args>
struct MethodCallerFactory
{
    typedef ReturnType (*Type)(ClassType*, Args...);

    template <ReturnType (ClassType::*Pointer)(Args...)>
    struct Method
    {
        static Type createMethodCaller()
        {
            ReturnType (*caller)(ClassType*, Args...) = [](ClassType* obj, Args ... args) -> ReturnType
            {
                 ReturnType (ClassType::*ptr)(Args...) = Pointer;
                                return (obj->*ptr)(args...);
            };
            return caller;
        }
   };
};


class Test
{
public :
        void set(const int& p)
        {
                n = p;
        }
        void set2(int p)
        {
                n = p;
        }
        void set3(const int p)
        {
                n = p;
        }
        void set4(int& p)
        {
                n = p;
        }
private :
        int n;
};

typedef int& INTREF;
typedef int INTVALUE;

int main()
{
        void (*ptr1)(Test*, const int&) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, const int&>::Method<&Test::set>::createMethodCaller();
        void (*ptr2)(Test*, const INTREF) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, const INTREF>::Method<&Test::set>::createMethodCaller();

        void (*ptr3)(Test*, int) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, int>::Method<&Test::set2>::createMethodCaller();
        void (*ptr4)(Test*, INTVALUE) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, INTVALUE>::Method<&Test::set2>::createMethodCaller();

        void (*ptr5)(Test*, int) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, const int>::Method<&Test::set3>::createMethodCaller();
        void (*ptr6)(Test*, const INTVALUE) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, const INTVALUE>::Method<&Test::set3>::createMethodCaller();

        void (*ptr7)(Test*, int&) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, int&>::Method<&Test::set4>::createMethodCaller();
        void (*ptr8)(Test*, INTREF) = MethodCallerFactory<Test, void, INTREF>::Method<&Test::set4>::createMethodCaller();
}
```

The only error i get is on the second pointer declaration :

> could not convert template argument ‘&Test::set’ to ‘void (Test::*)(int&)’
>     void (*ptr2)(Test*, const INTREF) = MethodCallerFactory::Method<&Test::set>::createMethodCaller();

It seem that when I use typedef with reference types, the compilator forget the const keyword. I dont understand why there is a problem with that.

Answer (score 6):

I guess plain text substitution tricked you into thinking that `const INTREF` would resolve to `const int&` (equivalent to `int const&`), but the substitution actually resolves to `int& const`, where `const` is eventually ignored (this is only the case because a `typedef` is involved, since you can't declare variables of type `int& const` explicitly). So what you end up with is `int&` rather than `int const&`.

In code:

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef int& INTREF;

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<const INTREF, int&>{}, "!");
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/035e162694d603a5)</kbd>

This is one of the reasons why some (including me) prefer to adopt the `const`-after style over the `const`-before style (the two styles are technically equivalent): apart from being more consistent,<sup>1</sup> it allows understanding what the compiler is doing by performing straightforward text substitution. If you had written `INTREF const` instead of `const INTREF`, you would have probably come to the correct conclusion.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can't always put the `const` qualifier before the type it qualifies, but you can always put it after. For instance, you can spell out the type "constant pointer to a constant integer" as `int const* const` (where the `const` keyword always applies to everything that comes before it), but the grammar does not allow writing `const const int*`; `const int* const` is allowed, but it mixes `const`-before and `const`-after, thus reducing consistency.